# What is the difference between the classic Taliban and TTP?

Tags: comparative-politics, taliban

What is the difference between the Taliban who is ruling the Islamic Emirate of Afghanistan, and TTP (Tehreek e Taliban Pakistan)?

Do they have any relationship?  Do they have any common goal?

Are they friends or enemies?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia page [Tehrik-i-Taliban Pakistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tehrik-i-Taliban_Pakistan)? It seems to contain a lot of information relevant to your question. Is there something you want to know that isn't there?

Comment: TTP has reportedly been consolidating various Islamist groups (former AQ, IS-K) and taking occasional potshots at Chinese BRI infrastructure projects in Pak. Since retaking all of Afghanistan, Afghan Taliban was asked to refrain from encouraging or supporting TTP, as one of the conditions of deeper recognition/support by central Asian powers. There are a bunch of news articles around late 2021 if you search.